# How to add Jbuttons that are in the JFrame to arraylist?

Tags: java, swing

I have designed a page that consists of some panels, labels and 60 buttons. I designed them using swing components by drag & drop.

Now I need to put all Jbuttons to arraylist how can I do that using a loop?

Comment: This depends on your code. Since we can't see your code, we can't answer your question. All I can say is, you'll have to call the `add()` method on your list.

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is example of finding buttons on the panel - you can try to adopt it to your case (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314183/how-to-access-controls-on-a-jpanel) post)

```
    Component[] components = aPanel.getComponents();
    if(components != null)
    {
        int numComponents = components.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < numComponents; i++)
        {
            Component c = components[i];
            if(c != null)
            {
                if(c instanceof JButton)
                {
                   // Add button to your list
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are welcome. Next time, when you put your question here, provide more details - its difficult to get suggestions without code and other details

Comment: since my code is too long I could not post it,sorry about that..